# 'What may it be'/ 'what may be it' which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, subject-verb-inversion, homework

I think,saying 'what may it be' is correct in the sense of something that i did not see before,it is new to me and on my hand.and i am saying this sentence "what may it be"/"what may be it".which one is correct? i dont know the structure.please tell me the structure.N.B it is necessary for my exam.

Comment: Please endeavour to pay closer attention to matters orthographical: capital letters, spacing, apostrophes, and all the rest of what goes into Standard English in her written form. Your postings are nearly incomprehensible.

Comment: I think you'd be more likely to explain "What can it be?" than "What may it be". *May* implies permission, which isn't relevant in the case you quote.

Comment: Ok.if i use 'can' in the sentence then tell me the structure.please please it is very important to me, sir.

Comment: Its very argent to know for my exam so give me a structure someone.

Comment: @ZaforAhmed If this is for an exam, it would be unethical of us to tell you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As standalone questions, “What may be it?” is incorrect or a fragment, while “What may it be?” is grammatical but unnatural in English, where one would instead say “What is it?” or “What can it be?”.

In future, questions like this may be better asked in [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).